# Disclaimer for App

Tags: copyright, privacy, disclaimers

I'm developing an App, through which illustrators/creators can distribute their own comic books for free and other readers can download the books for free as well. I don't want anyone to distribute comic books that don't belong to them or they don't have right to distribute them. Even if they do, the app doesn't hold any liability for that. How can I write a disclaimer for this.
  I'm a developer and don't have any knowledge in this law domain. My apologies if the question seems irrelevant. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I write a disclaimer for this

You can't.

As a host of content you must have policies and procedures in place to deal with allegations of copyright infringement (such as takedown requests). This is a legal obligation on you that you cannot avoid with a disclaimer.

Hire a lawyer.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Does that mean, if I monitor the contents and respond the allegations, i.e. delete contents if needed, I am safe? If so, what happens with the circulation of the content that has already taken place? Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @Ranadhir you need to hire a lawyer to ask detailed questions like that of